# Disable all lazy loading or force eager loading for a LINQ context

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have a document generator which contains queries for about 200 items at the moment but will likely be upwards of 500 when complete. I've recently noticed that some of the mappings denote lazy loading. This presents a problem for the document generator as it needs access to all of these properties based on which document is being generated.

While I am aware of the `DataLoadOptions` that can be specified to the context, this would result in me having to explicitly specify every column that could possibly be loaded. That is north of 1000 as it all of the data fetching takes place in one context.

Is there any way for me to disable lazy loading for a context or explicitly enable eager loading to ignore the defer loading property? Perhaps extending the DB context class and overriding something?

Comment: Final solution: http://gist.github.com/506573

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need to set [`DeferredLoadingEnabled`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386920%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), and then include every property using some reflection like:

```
DataLoadOptions dataLoadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();

foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(SomeThingyClass).GetProperties())
{
    ParameterExpression paramExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(SomeThingyClass), "s");
    Expression expr = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(paramExp, pi.Name), typeof(object));
    LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, paramExp);
    dataLoadOptions.LoadWith((Expression<Func<SomeThingyClass, object>>) lambda);
}
```

Comment: btw, what's DeferredLoadingEnabled in EF terms? Is it the same as context.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true?

Comment: The properties are all in different tables as well. If I iterate those too using the `GetProperties()` method of the context how can I filter out only the `System.Data.Linq.Table` ones?

Comment: Easiest is checking whether `pi.PropertyType.Name == "Table`1"`

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky with LINQ to SQL.  The short answer is, it depends.

If your entities are laid out in a manner such that you have a relationship that mirrors this:

`Customers -> Orders -> OrderDetails`

And you need to evaluate properties on all 3 entities in order to make a decision, your best bet is to go with writing a join.  Using `.LoadWith` will fetch `Customers` and `Orders` using a single statement, but then will issue a query for every single `OrderDetails` record as well.

So, even if you did specify every child relationship with LoadWith, you're not going to get a single query issued to retrieve the result.

Comment: All of the properties are only on the object being selected. No relationships will be followed after the fact.